# MS SQL update same column in multiple tables using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, database-cursor

I have a database containing a lot of tables, most of which have a column called `contract` which is a varchar(255) and is used as a foreign key.  The following query selects all table names that contain this column (33 in total):

```
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'contract'
) AND name <> N'sysdercv'
```

Now, I need to change all of the contract names (not many) into anonymous identifiers so I can use screenshots without revealing sensitive data, but I need to maintain the relationships so the application still works.  Essentially, I want to change all instances of contract='SomeCompany' to contract='example1' in all of the tables returned by the above query.

My initial attempt to do so is as follows:

```
declare @tablename sysname

declare C cursor fast_forward for
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'contract'
) AND name <> N'sysdercv'

open C
fetch next from C into @tablename

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    update @tablename set contract='example1' where contract='SomeCompany'
    fetch next from C into @tablename
end

close C
deallocate C
go
```

However, this gives the error `Must declare the table variable "@tablename".`

So my questions are:

1. Is what I am trying to do possible, or do I need to manually go through and update all the tables myself?
2. If so, am I on the right lines or am I barking up entirely the wrong proverbial tree?

Comment: There is agreement that [tag:cursor] (and therefore [tag:cursors]) [deserve removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250926/split-cursor-into-more-specific-tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the code thinks you have a table variable called @tablename

```
DECLARE @tablename TABLE (SomeCol...)
```

This won't work if you do this because object names in almost all DML or DDL can not be parameterised with variables.

You have to do this

```
SET @sql = 'update ' + @tablename + 
                ' set contract=''example1'' where contract=''SomeCompany'''
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: It is possible to avoid of using cursor:  '
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SELECT @sSQL+=
'UPDATE '+ name + ' set contract=''example1'' where contract=''SomeCompany''' +CHAR(13)
FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'contract'
) AND name <> N'sysdercv'
EXECUTE(@sSQl)'